ModuleNotFoundError message using Python
I'm trying to create an API using Python. In my app folder there are the folders: models, services, tests. In each folder (including app) there is an empty __init__.py
In my model folder there is Ad.py file.
In my services folder there is an AdService.py file.
This is part of the code in my AdService.py file:
from models.Ad import Ad
from models.SubCategory import SubCategory
from database import session


class AdService:
    .
    .
    .

In my tests folder there is a file name AdServiceTest.py.
This is part of the code in my AdServiceTest.py file:
import unittest
from datetime import datetime
from app.models.Ad import Ad  # Ensure the import path is correct
from app.services.AdService import AdService  # Ensure the import path is correct
from app.database import (Base,engine,session)  # Assuming Base and engine are defined in your database module
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Setup in-memory SQLite database for testing
DATABASE_URL = "XXXX"
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(Session)


class AdServiceTest(unittest.TestCase):
.
.
.

When I run my AdServiceTest.py I get an error on the line: "from app.models.Ad import Ad" with the text:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'".

I tried changing the prefix to just models.Ad or ..models.Ad and nothing worked.
What am I doing wrong?

What happens if you just delete the app. from each import line?

There might be no __init__.py in app so it thinks that app is not a module. It is just a guess without seeing a project structure it is hard to tell.

If I remove the "app." from each import line the error message changes to "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'". And in my app folder there is a init.py file.
